# How to move the souce code from one repository to another repository without using fork in Git?

Tags: git, github

I want to move source code from my own repository to organization repository with out using the fork in git, is there any alternative way to achieve this.

I have tried fork the repo but after fork when i delete my own repo it is deleting from Organization as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for github, but if you have a repository with your code and you would like to preserve a history, you can:

1. Clone the repository (`git clone...`)
2. Add a remote repository (in this case, the repository of your organization) to your current repo: `git remote add target <address_of_the_organization_repo>`
   At this point you show have two different remote locations: use `git remote -vv` to make sure that that's indeed the case.
3. Push the data to that repository (assuming its empty of course):
   `git push -u target --all`

Comment: You'll usually want to start with `git clone --bare`, maybe even `git clone --mirror`, and end with `git push --mirror`.

Comment: And don't forget `git lfs fetch --all` and `git lfs push --all` in case you're using git LFS.